# IllegalArgumentException with Spark 1.6

Tags: apache-spark

I'm running Spark 1.6.0 on CDH 5.7 and I've upgraded my original application from 1.4.1 to 1.6.0. When I try to run my application (which previously worked fine) I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed
        at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:221)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$$anonfun$prepareLocalResources$6$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Client.scala:473)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$$anonfun$prepareLocalResources$6$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Client.scala:471)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$$anonfun$prepareLocalResources$6.apply(Client.scala:471)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$$anonfun$prepareLocalResources$6.apply(Client.scala:469)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.prepareLocalResources(Client.scala:469)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.createContainerLaunchContext(Client.scala:725)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.submitApplication(Client.scala:143)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:1023)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$.main(Client.scala:1083)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.main(Client.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

I submit the application with:

- `--jars` is a comma-separated list of jars (with absolute paths)
- `--files` is a comma-separated list of files (with absolute paths)
- `--driver-class-path` is a colon-separated list of resources (without the full path, just the file names)

I have tried it with full paths for the driver (and executor) class paths, but that gives me the same issue. All files and jars submitted with the app exist, I checked.

Could this be related to the issue with [duplicates in the distributed cache](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-14423) or is this another issue?

From the source code I see that the only calls to `require` without a custom message (as in the stack trace) are related to the `distribute()` method. If so, how can I run applications without upgrading Spark?

Comment: Looks to me like it's missing a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

This is the exception which results from having the same path/URI appear twice in the argument to the `--files` option.